# How to get set environment variable expression

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7, cmd, mingw

How to configure **Windows 7** `environment` `variable` from batch file and reuse the existing `user`/`system` `variable` `expression` rather than its value

Regarding the bat command, lets say

```
echo %TEMP%
```

**output:**

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp
```

**desired output:**

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp
```

Again while I trying to set environment variable permanently

```
setx CHORKE_TEMP "%TEMP%\chorke"
```

**it set:**

```
CHORKE_TEMP=C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\chorke
```

**expectation:**

```
CHORKE_TEMP=%TEMP%\chorke
```

Am I missing any option?

Answer (score 1):

#### Output produced by the following script:

```
1: "C:\Users\james\AppData\Local\Temp\chorke"
2: "%TEMP%\chorke"
```

#### Script:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set CHORKE_TEMP="%TEMP%\chorke"
echo 1: %CHORKE_TEMP%

set CHORKE_TEMP="%%TEMP%%\chorke"
echo 2: %CHORKE_TEMP%
```